# Is there a way to connect a device to ad hoc wifi network via WPS on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

**Context:**

I have a printer (Samsung ML-2165w) that only connects to wifi via WPS. I just moved to a building with manage wifi by an IPS that I have no control over. And their wifi doesn't allow devices to see each other.

So I want to try connecting the printer to an ad hoc wifi network on the computer.

**Question:**

Is there a way to connect a device to ad hoc wifi network via WPS on Windows 7?

Comment: What printer? (make/model)

Comment: As David said please add the printer model/make to get a better idea of what to answer.

Comment: edited. Thanks for the reminders. I configured the printer using a cable (never managed to make the usb connection work on this printer before). I am still curious whether WPS can be used with an ad hoc network on windows.